# Creating an object from an array of multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I have this function:

```
function getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier) {
$url = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.spaces($query).'&fields='.$fields.'&limit='.$limit.'&until='.$until);
 $j = json_decode($url);
  foreach($j->data as $v) {
  if ($v->type == $type) {
        $author_id = $v->from->id;
        $original_id = $v->id;
        $post_url = getPostUrl($original_id, $author_id);
        //$description = stopWords($v->message);
        $description = $v->message;
        $pub_date = $v->created_time;
        $post[]= array(
        'author_id' => $author_id, 
        'orginal_id' => $original_id, 
        'post_url' => $post_url, 
        'descritpion' => $description, 
        'pub_date' => $pub_date
        );
    }
 }  
 return (object)$post;
}
```

If I call for example:

```
$post = getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier);

echo $post->pub_date;`
```

it returns empty..

I tried to strip the [] from the $post array in the function...and in this case it returns only ONE value..

Instead it should return more values, because the object should get more values from the foreach loop in the above function..

But it's not happening..

I tried also to work with normal arrays, without an object, like this:

```
$post = getPostInfo($query, $fields, $type, $limit, $since, $until, $lang, $stopwords, $identifier);

echo $post['pub_date'];
```

In this case it always returns NULL..

What I am doing wrong?

How to assign more values to the array and getting them back when I need, knowing that the things I get should contain more values. It's like an array of an array...

I am a little confused..

I like the solution with objects, but if there is any other way, then better.

This is an example of what I get from the array $post:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(10) "1319929690" ["orginal_id"]=> string(24) "1319929690_2736172406396" ["post_url"]=> string(77) "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2736172406396&id=1319929690" ["descritpion"]=> string(773) "It was only a matter of time. # How do they serve alcoholic drinks on Italian cruise ships? - On the rocks # What vegetables do you get with dinner on Italian cruise ships? - Leeks # What's the fastest way to get off an Italian cruise ship? - Follow the captain # When the captain of the ill fated Costa Concordia was asked if he knew where he was going he replied "off course." # So the captain of the Costa Concordia will soon be in the dock. That's more than can be said for his ship. # The Costa Concordia is probably the most expensive thing to go down in Italy since Berlusconi's last hooker. # What's the difference between the Italian economy and the stricken cruise liner Costa Concordia? Nothing - The bottoms dropped out of both." ["pub_date"]=> string(24) "2012-02-04T14:36:54+0000" } [1]=> array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(10) "1721122272" ["orginal_id"]=> string(24) "1721122272_1862454417365" ["post_url"]=> string(77) "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1862454417365&id=1721122272" ["descritpion"]=> string(1968) "ThÃ¡ch thÃ ng nÃ o quÃ¡nh tao 1. Má»¸: â€œTao muá»‘n Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng nÃ o, lÃ  tao Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³. NgoÃ i ra, tao bao tiá»n sÃºng!â€ 2. NATO: â€œMá»¹ Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng nÃ o, tao Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€. 3. NGA: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o báº­t tao, tao cáº¯t dáº§u lá»­a!â€. 4. ISRAEL: â€œtháº±ng nÃ o ngáº¥m ngáº§m muá»‘n Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€. 5. NHáº¬T: â€œtháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao sáº½ báº£o Má»¹ Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³. Náº¿u chÃºng mÃ y khÃ´ng ngá»«ng táº¥n cÃ´ng, tao cho Maria Ozawa nghá»‰ viá»‡c!â€. 6. TRUNG QUá»C: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o gáº§n tao, tao Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€. 7. ÄÃ€I LOAN: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã²i Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao báº£o bÃ¡o chÃ­ chá»­i tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€. 8. NAM HÃ€N: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘á»‹nh Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao táº­p tráº­n vá»›i tháº±ng Má»¹!â€. 9. Báº®C HÃ€N: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o lÃ m tao bá»±c, tao sáº½ Ä‘Ã¡nh tháº±ng Nam HÃ n!â€. 10. Berlusconi (ITALIA): â€œTháº±ng nÃ o oÃ¡nh tao, taoâ€¦ ngá»§ vá»›i vá»£ tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€. 11. SINGAPORE : â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao?!Cháº¯c Ä‘áº¿k tháº±ng nÃ o ráº£nh mÃ  Ä‘i Ä‘Ã¡nh tao!â€. 12. IRAQ : â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao thÃ¬ cá»© Ä‘Ã¡nh cho Ä‘Ã£, chá»«ng nÃ o má»‡t thÃ¬ tá»± Ä‘á»™ng vá»!â€. 13. ARAP SAUDI : â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao mua tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³!â€ 14. Billaden: â€œTháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, tao khá»§ng bá»‘ tháº±ng Má»¹!â€. 15. LiÃªn Hiá»‡p Quá»‘c: â€œTao dÃ¡n cÃ¡i mÃ¡câ€¦ vÃ¹ng cáº¥m bay lÃªn tháº±ng nÃ o, chÃºng mÃ y Ãºp sá»t tháº±ng Ä‘áº¥y cho tao!â€. 16. CUBA : â€œTháº±ng nÃ o oÃ¡nh tao, tao cho Viá»‡t Nam má»™t mÃ¬nh canh giá»¯ tháº¿ giá»›i!â€. 17. VIá»†T NAM: â€œChá»— nÃ o cÃ³ oÃ¡nh nhau, tao bÃ y tá» quan ngáº¡i sÃ¢u sáº¯c. CÃ²n tháº±ng nÃ o oÃ¡nh tao, tao tuyÃªn bá»‘ chá»§ quyá»n, tao cáº¯t Ä‘iá»‡n luÃ¢n phiÃªn, sau Ä‘Ã³ taoâ€¦ cá»±c lá»±c lÃªn Ã¡n!â€. 18. THá»¤Y SÄ¨ : Tháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, Tao khÃ³a tÃ i khoáº£n tiá»n quá»‘c gia tháº±ng Ä‘Ã³. 19. PHILIPIN : â€ Tháº±ng nÃ o Ä‘Ã¡nh tao, muá»‘n há»©ng bÃ£o qua mÃ  Ä‘Ã¡nh. =]]" ["pub_date"]=> string(24) "2012-02-04T13:50:47+0000" } [2]=> array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(9) "594958865" ["orginal_id"]=> string(27) "594958865_10150583915793866" ["post_url"]=> string(80) "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10150583915793866&id=594958865" ["descritpion"]=> string(717) "# How do they serve alcoholic drinks on Italian cruise ships? - On the rocks # What vegetables do you get with dinner on Italian cruise ships? - Leeks # What's the fastest way to get off an Italian cruise ship? - Follow the captain # When the captain of the ill fated Costa Concordia was asked if he knew where he was going he replied "off course." # So the captain of the Costa Concordia will soon be in the dock. That's more than can be said for his ship. # The Costa Concordia is probably the most expensive thing to go down in Italy since Berlusconi's last hooker. # What's the difference between the Italian economy and the stricken cruise liner Costa Concordia? Nothing - The bottoms dropped out of both." ["pub_date"]=> string(24) "2012-02-04T13:15:45+0000" } [3]=> array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(10) "1561522855" ["orginal_id"]=> string(24) "1561522855_2516825610916" ["post_url"]=> string(77) "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2516825610916&id=1561522855" ["descritpion"]=> string(410) "Monti "frainteso" sulla monotonia del posto fisso??? Come Berlusconi che smentiva le proprie dichiarazioni mezzora dopo averle fatte??? Ma fatemi il piacere!!! La cosa che piÃ¹ mi fa specie Ã© assistere all'atteggiamento di tanti antiberlusconiani di maniera che ieri si stracciavano le vesti per ogni cazzata che proveniva da Arcore e che oggi sono pronti a digerire politiche ed esternazioni anche peggiori!!" ["pub_date"]=> string(24) "2012-02-04T12:46:50+0000" } [4]=> array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(9) "749211731" ["orginal_id"]=> string(27) "749211731_10150528401901732" ["post_url"]=> string(80) "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10150528401901732&id=749211731" ["descritpion"]=> string(265) "B. al Financial Times: "Mi farÃ² da parte dalla politica attiva e non ho nessuna intenzione di candidarmi ancora a primo ministro". Bossi: "Se Berlusconi si ritira Ã¨ risolto il problema". La solida alleanza parlamentare che ha governato l'Italia in questi 20 anni." ["pub_date"]=> string(24) "2012-02-04T11:57:05+0000" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it out like this

```
echo $post[0]["author_id"];
echo $post[1]["author_id"];
```

You can also use a for each loop if you need to display all the values at once

```
foreach($post as $p){
   echo $p["author_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick to arrays personally, so return with `return $post;`

You would have to echo `$post[0]['pub_date'];` or `$post[1]['pub_date'];` or `$post[2]['pub_date'];` for the different rows.

Or you can loop

```
foreach ($post as $post_values){
    echo $post_values['pub_date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing somehting like this

```
    $post[] = (object) array(
            'author_id' => $author_id,
            'orginal_id' => $original_id,
            'post_url' => $post_url,
            'description' => $description,
            'pub_date' => $pub_date
    );
```